# Can I use a content in a cell to store extract the tab name of an xls formula?

Tags: xlsx, xls

I have an xls formula as below

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A2, '2018-01.csv'!$A:$B, 2, FALSE), 0)
```

where by `2018-01.csv` it the tab name.

Can I replace this tab name and defined in a cell? e.g.

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A2, '${J1}.csv'!$A:$B, 2, FALSE), 0)
```

Whereby `${J1}` will take the value from cell `J1` which containt `2018-01`?

Note `${j1}` is a wrong syntax in xls in that formula. Looking if there's one way to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. It's by using INDIRECT.

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A2,INDIRECT("'"&J$1&".csv'!"&"$A:$B"), 2, FALSE), 0)
```

Where cell `J$1` is where it content `2018-01`

Thanks to sharing in http://spreadsheetpro.net/how-to-make-a-dynamic-reference-to-a-worksheet-in-excel-and-google-spreadsheets/